# galaxy s iii web browser DisplayModeProvider "MVC4"

Tags: mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, samsung-mobile

my application is MVC4, it works great with iPhone and Windows Phone, but did not work with Samsung Galaxy S III, it displays Desktop user interface! I tried several InexOf, for example:

```
 DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("Mobile")
            {
                ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent()
                    .IndexOf("Linux", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            });
```

I also tried:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("Mobile")
{
    ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent()
        .IndexOf("Opera Mobi", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
});
```

I checked the Samsung III browser, using an older MVC3 application that I have developed, here are the borwser Information:
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0(Linux, U; Android 4.0.4 ....
Browser: Safari
Model SGH-1747M

I would appreciate your suggestions.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone has the same problem.  I stared a new project in MVC4 (I was using the Beta version of MVC4 before)  Install-Package jQuery.Mobile.MVC; It works now.  The problem was not related to Samsung, becasue I tried the application on LG Android and had the same issue.   Also I added in Global file the following:

```
   DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("Linux")
           {
               ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf
                   ("Linux", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
           });
```